# Ошибка экспорта данных из DataGrid в Excel | C# WPF + SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, excel

Данные хранятся в бд SQL и выводятся в DataGrid
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace kyrsa4
{
    class ExcelExportSheet
    {
        public ExcelExportSheet(DataGrid dataGrid, DateTime dt)
        {
            Application excel = new Application();
            excel.Visible = true;
            Worksheet sheet1 = excel.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value).Sheets[1];

            sheet1.Range["A1:F1"].Merge();
            sheet1.Range["A2:F2"].Merge();

            string title = "Пример";

            sheet1.Range["A1:F1"].Value = title;
            sheet1.Range["A1:F1"].Font.Bold = true;
            sheet1.Range["A2:F2"].Value = dt.ToShortDateString();

            for(int j=0; j<dataGrid.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                Range myRange = (Range)sheet1.Cells[4, j + 1];
                myRange.Font.Bold = true;
                string header = dataGrid.Columns[j].Header.ToString();
                sheet1.Columns[j + 1].ColumnWidth = header.Length + 5;
                myRange.Value2 = header;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGrid.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                var item = dataGrid.Items[j] as ClientsmfcEntities11;

                sheet1.Cells[j + 5, 1].Value = item.Client;


            }
                


        }
    }
}



private void Button_Click_7(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ExcelExportSheet export = new ExcelExportSheet(dg2, DateTime.Now);
        }
```

При этом в Excel файле пишутся имена столбцов без данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам ведь прямым текстом написало, что `item == null`. Смотрим что за `item` и видим это `var item = dataGrid.Items[j] as ClientsmfcEntities11;`, дальше уже под отладкой смотрите, верный вы тип указали или нет, есть-ли там то, чего вы ожидаете, и так далее.

Comment: item - переменная, которая должна хранить данные датагрида. примеры находил, только где напрямую к объектам обращаются, чтобы их вывести. а у меня все данные изначально в sql лежат и как к отдельной строке обратиться, чтобы ее прочитало и вывело я не имею представления

Comment: Мне не надо пояснять что это, это вы сами должны четко понимать что и как. Еще раз повторю, смотрите под отладкой, что у вас в `Items[j]`, действительно там объект `ClientsmfcEntities11` или нечто другое? Там есть вообще нужные вам данные? А так, если хотите мое мнение, то вы все делаете не так, ибо WPF это привязки, а не хранение данные в UI... В грамотном WPF проекте у вас должна быть простая коллекция данных, к которой вы привязываете UI, который в свою очередь отображает вам как надо. Взять/добавить/удалить данные - все это вы делать должны с коллекцией, а не с UI.